# Changing a const variable with a pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Look at this program:

```
int main(){
    const int a_const=10;
    int * const a=const_cast<int * const>(&a_const);
    *a=5;
}
```

So the address of `a_const` and the pointer  `a` have the same value.
But changing the value of what `a` is pointing to, doesn't `a_const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*. It *appearing* to be possible is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

You are not allowed to attempt to change the value of a variable that was declared as `const`, by using a non-`const` pointer (or reference) that has been obtained as a result of a `const_cast`.

(If it appears to work in this case, try the equivalent with a read only-string literal - that will cause a crash on very many platforms.)

Comment: Nitpick: if behavior is *undefined*, you can't say it's *not possible*. Undefined behavior, by definition, cannot rule out any behavior;)

Comment: @el.pescado: Yes, precision is important. I've amended.